comma is not showing in the Hybrid app keyboard(inputmode="decimal") in iOS and Android devices
I am using the below vuejs code for showing the numeric keyboard in my Hybrid mobile app. Currently its not showing the comma(,) in the keyboard. Can anyone help to display the comma(,) in the numeric type keyboard. I don't want to use other type(text) keyboard. Thanks in advance.
<FormInput
        id="value"
        ref="input"
        type="number"
        inputmode="decimal"
        pattern="[0-9]\.]*"
        class="vital-input"
        v-model="model.data.value"
        :min="model.data.unit.limits.MIN_VALUE"
        :max="model.data.unit.limits.MAX_VALUE"
        :hasError="!!model.errors.value"
        :errorMessage="model.errors.value"
        :disabled="!!bluetoothDevice"
        :placeholder="bluetoothPlaceholder"
        @input="handleInput"
      />


Could you show us what the FormInput component looks like? Or where did you import it from if it's a library?

hi @KrzysztofKrzeszewski
<input
:type="type"
:id="id"
class="form-input"
ref="input"
:value="value"
@input="handleInput($event)"
v-bind:class="{ 'input-error': hasError }"
:inputmode="inputmode"
:autofocus="autofocus"
:autocapitalize="autocapitalize"
:placeholder="placeholder"
:disabled="disabled === true"
:step="step"
:max="max"
:min="min"
:pattern="pattern"
/>

I think the issue lays in the pattern property as It looks broken to me. Could you try removing it altogether to see if that helps? Then we can investigate how to fix it if that was the issue.

Sure. will remove the pattern and try it out @KrzysztofKrzeszewski

@KrzysztofKrzeszewski i was removed the pattern and tried it but still there is no luck.
